# transpose 3D array and multiply elementwise-memory contiguity

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have a huge 3D array that looks like `A.shape = (100000, 5000, 50)`. 
I need to transpose it to have an array of the form `A.shape = (50, 5000, 100000)`. 
Then I need to do the operation `a = a.T @ a` on each of the 50 matrices contained in A. 
This gives me a 3D array of the form `A.shape = (50, 5000, 5000)`.

If I do this with `A.transpose(2, 1, 0) @ A.transpose(2, 0, 1)` the single matrix multiplications 
`a = a.T @ a` turn out to be a thousand times slower than the case where `a` were not extracted from `A`.

The problem is that after transposing, the 3D array is not contiguous. 
I tried use `np.ascontiguousarray()` or `copy()` after transposing. It improves but it is still slower and it spends quite some time for copying.

Could any one suggest a better choice ? 
In particular I am trying to use `np.einsum` but I could not.

Comment: Due to memory management issues, iterating the small 50 dimension might be fastest.

Comment: It is indeed. It is nearly twice faster than inserting the stack of 50 matrices in matmul. It is surprising that a looping can do better than numpy.

Comment: A small number of loops on a complicated task often is faster than a more memory intensive 'pure' numpy version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
A = ...
b = np.einsum('jki,jli->ikl', A, A)
print(b.shape)
# (50, 5000, 5000)
```

Comment: Thank you for the correct expression. The stack of matrices returned by einsum in this case is not in C order, thus unpractical for the operations I want to do afterwards with each of the matrices. It is also very slow.